# All modules with given order principal implies PIR - Koch ANT

Tags: commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

Let $K$ be a number field. A *complete module* $m$ in $K$ is a finitely generated additive subgroup of $K$ of rank $[K:\Bbb Q]$. To a complete module $m$ we associate its order ${\cal O}(m)=\{x\in K\mid xm\subseteq m\}\subseteq {\cal O}_K$.

Let $\cal O$ be any order in $K$. Suppose every complete module $m$ with $\cal O(m)=O$ is of the form $\alpha \cal O$ for some $\alpha\in K$. In Koch's "Algebraic Number Theory", p. 12 it is claimed that that this implies that $\cal O$ is a principal ideal ring.

Why is that?

The problem I have is that if $I$ is an ideal of $\cal O$, then it is not necessarily the case that ${\cal O}(I)=\cal O$, so we can't conclude immediately from the assumption that $I$ is principal.